# Error in calculating Implied Volatility in R

Tags: r, shiny, quantmod

I've been able to successfully plot volatility of a stock and I have now moved on in calculating a stocks historical implied volatility using historical closing pricing using quantmod. Here is my code below, but the error I am getting is throwing me off. I am new to this language and definitely having a bit of a learning curve, any input is much appreciated:

```
library(quantmod)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(RND)
source("helpers.R")


ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Realized Voltility"),
    helpText("Select a stock to examine. Information will be collected from Yahoo finance."),
    textInput("symb", "Symbol", value="SPY"),
    dateRangeInput("dates","Date range",start = "2020-09-01",end = as.character(Sys.Date())),
    plotOutput("plot")
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        
        ##Get stock price data
        price <- getSymbols(req(input$symb), src = "yahoo",
                            from = input$dates[1],
                            to = input$dates[2],
                            auto.assign = FALSE)
        
        ##plot volitility based on price dataframe
        vol <- volatility(price,n=25,N=252,calc="close")
        
        ##set values for BS computation of Implied Vol
        r = 0.05
        y = 0.02
        te = 60/365
        s0 = 400
        
        ##run through function to set option price range
        sigma.range = seq(from = 0.1, to = 0.8, by = 0.05)
        callPrice.range = floor(seq(from = 300, to = 500, length.out = length(sigma.range)))
        bsm.calls = numeric(length(sigma.range))
        for (i in 1:length(sigma.range))
        {
            bsm.calls[i] = price.bsm.option(r = r, te = te, s0 = s0, k = callPrice.range[i],
                                            sigma = sigma.range[i], y = y)$call
        }
        bsm.calls
        
        ##set call price range
        callPrice.range
        
        ##loop through dataframe 'price' and compute IV for each closing day value based on variables r, te, s0, k, y, callPrice.range, and set lower/upper range
        iVol <- for (i in price) {
            impliedVol = compute.implied.volatility(r = r, te = te, s0 = s0,k = i, y = y, callPrice.range = bsm.calls, lower = 0.001, upper = 0.999)
            
            ##for each computr value of IV, paste it in the console to start
            print(paste("CLosing Price = ", impliedVol))
        }
        
        ##chart it all
        chartSeries(vol)
    })
    
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Error message received is the following:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5727
Warning: Error in compute.implied.volatility: unused argument (callPrice.range = bsm.calls)
  167: renderPlot [/Users/nobility/DevProjects/ShinyOptionsPractice/app.R#63]
  165: func
  125: drawPlot
  111: <reactive:plotObj>
   95: drawReactive
   82: origRenderFunc
   81: output$plot
    1: runApp
```

My expected outcome is a print to the console of the various calculated implied volatility for each strike price (close price) as follows:

```
[1] "Implied Vol =  339.390015"
[1] "Implied Vol =  338.220001"
[1] "Implied Vol =  326.660004"
[1] "Implied Vol =  329.980011"
[1] "Implied Vol =  326.540009"
[1] "Implied Vol =  330.200012"
[1] "Implied Vol =  336.029999"
[1] "Implied Vol =  343.540009"
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because `compute.implied.volatility()` doesn't have a `callPrice.range` argument. You probably meant to use `call.price`.

The function definition is:

`compute.implied.volatility(r, te, s0, k, y, call.price, lower, upper)`

So you need to update your call to:

```r
impliedVol = compute.implied.volatility(r = r, te = te, s0 = s0, k = i,
    y = y, call.price = bsm.calls, lower = 0.001, upper = 0.999)
```

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to have fixed the one error... now I got another: Warning: Error in uniroot: f() values at end points not of opposite sign

Answer (score 0):

Your print statement inside `output$plot` will not work as the final output it renders is just a plot.  So, you need to print it outside the `output$plot`, but within a observer as you are using user input variable `input$symb` and dates.  Console output is shown at the bottom of the picture below.

Try this

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Realized Voltility"),
  helpText("Select a stock to examine. Information will be collected from Yahoo finance."),
  textInput("symb", "Symbol", value="SPY"),
  dateRangeInput("dates","Date range",start = "2020-09-01",end = as.character(Sys.Date())),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observe({
    ##Get stock price data
    price <- getSymbols(req(input$symb), src = "yahoo",
                        from = input$dates[1],
                        to = input$dates[2],
                        auto.assign = FALSE)
    
    ##plot volitility based on price dataframe
    vol <- volatility(price,n=25,N=252,calc="close")
    
    ##set values for BS computation of Implied Vol
    r = 0.05
    y = 0.02
    te = 60/365
    s0 = 400
    
    ##run through function to set option price range
    sigma.range = seq(from = 0.1, to = 0.8, by = 0.05)
    callPrice.range = floor(seq(from = 300, to = 500, length.out = length(sigma.range)))
    bsm.calls = numeric(length(sigma.range))
    for (i in 1:length(sigma.range))
    {
      bsm.calls[i] = price.bsm.option(r = r, te = te, s0 = s0, k = callPrice.range[i],
                                      sigma = sigma.range[i], y = y)$call
    }
    bsm.calls
    
    ##set call price range
    callPrice.range
    
    impliedVol = compute.implied.volatility(r = r, te = te, s0 = s0, k = callPrice.range, y = y, 
                               call.price = bsm.calls, lower = 0.001, upper = 0.999)
    sigma.range
    print(paste("CLosing Price = ", impliedVol))
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      
      ##chart it all
      chartSeries(vol)
    })
    
  })
  
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: I am torn - because this certainly works (the app runs w/o error) but the goal is to run the "compute.implied.volatility()" against each data element in the "price" dataframe and print out its computed value to the console. The answer provided prints out a set number of calcs that never change, which really should differ depending on what is input by the user as a "Symbol"

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with the function `compute.implied.volatility()`.  I do not see a dependency between `input$symb` and `compute.implied.volatility()`.  You can change the observer to `observeEvent`, but the console shows the same output each time you type a new stock symbol.

Comment: Thanks, its a function derived from the RND package in rstudio - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RND/RND.pdf

having the console print stock specific data for each input symbol is what i am after.